# I'm trying to collect the text with BeautifulSoup using python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

I want to know how I can collect the desire data with beautiful soup here is the code and trying to collect the text data that is "RoSharon1977"

I'm trying using

```
<div id="twitter" class="editable-item">
  <div id="twitter-view">
     <ul><li>
        <a href="/redir/redirect?url=http%3A%2F%2Ftwitter%2Ecom%2FRoSharon1977&amp;urlhash=QRJD">RoSharon1977</a>
     </li></ul>
</div></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to find the `div` by its `id`, then get the next `ul` element, etc and continuing to drill down until you reach the `a` element, then get the text of it:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''<div id="twitter" class="editable-item">
  <div id="twitter-view">
     <ul><li>
        <a href="/redir/redirect?url=http%3A%2F%2Ftwitter%2Ecom%2FRoSharon1977&amp;urlhash=QRJD">RoSharon1977</a>
     </li></ul>
</div></div>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

print soup.find('div', attrs={'id': 'twitter-view'}).findNext('ul').findNext('li').findNext('a').text
```

Or depending on how the whole webpage looks you could simply do:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

print soup.find('a').text
```

And if there are multiple `a` elements:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

for a in soup.find_all('a'):
    print a.text
```